# How to set the last input of my form to be the default value using jquery without using a database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, symfony

I am just new to symfony framework and still working on how to set the last input in my form (e.g., strength: 79) as the default value of my progressbar without using the database after refreshing the page.

Here is some part of my code: index.html.twig

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Set chest targets</legend>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="responsivelabel aligninline" >
        <label>Strength:</label>
        </div>

        <div class="responsiveelement aligninline" >
        goal: 
        <input type="text" size="3" id="strength_goal" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="responsivelabel aligninline" >
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
        <div class="responsiveelement aligninline" >
            <p class = "clean-gray">Save Changes</p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is some part of my code: index.html.twig

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p.clean-gray").on('click', function(){
            var str = $("#strength_goal").val();
            var mov = $("#movement_goal").val();

            $("div.strength").css("width", str+'%')
            $("div.movement").css("width", mov+'%');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Some part of the code: index.html.twig

```
strength
<div class="prog-barwrap mini">
    <div class="prog-bar strength" style="width:0%" ></div>
</div>  
movement
<div class="prog-barwrap mini">
    <div class="prog-bar movement" style="width:0%"></div>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to do it. Others say i should use session but i dont know how to do it in symfony. Thanks in advance. I am currently using 2.3 version.

I tried visiting the w3school: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_defaultvalue3
It tells me how to set the default value but is it possible to make the last data i inputed into the form as the new default value?

Comment: localstorage can be used to persist data, beyond that,its not entirely clear what your code should do so its hard to help

Comment: @DelightedD0D  sir, how do i do that using the localstorage? 
and how about if i am using my own server in webmin.?

Comment: Does your page reloads after saving the details? If not you can maintain previous value in JavaScript itself.

Comment: @Samir sir, that is actually my problem a while back. I used _<button>Save Changes</button>_  as my button and the values refreshes and go back to 0 as i refresh my page.

Comment: In that case you can use `localStorage` as suggested by DelightedD0D. Refer this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: thanks sir.. i'll update you if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to locally store the last values entered by a user.

If so, this is something that I have to do often, This is the method I use.

Simply include the below javascript then when you do your html, add  `data-local-key="someKeyName"` to any element you want to store the last value for (where you name someKeyName whatever you want with no spaces). When the user inputs data and clicks away, the value is saved. When the page loads, it will automatically search for stored values and re-input them. Add as many elements as your heart desires with no additional js code.

#### [Here is a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/6392xe1L/)

```
<input type="text" id="test" data-local-key="someKeyName" value="some initial value">
```

**The javascript:**

```
/**
 * Feature detect + local reference for simple use of local storage
 * Use like:
 * if (storage) {
 *    storage.setItem('key', 'value');
 *    storage.getItem('key');
 * }
 *
 */
var storage;
var fail;
var uid;
try {
  uid = new Date;
  (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
  fail = storage.getItem(uid) != uid;
  storage.removeItem(uid);
  fail && (storage = false);
} catch (exception) {}

// using the feature
$(function() {

  $(document).on('blur', '[data-local-key]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (storage) {
      storage.setItem($this.data('local-key'), $this.val());
    }
  });
  if (storage) {
    $('[data-local-key]').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var storedVal = storage.getItem($this.data('local-key'));
      if(storedVal) $this.val(storedVal);
    });
  }
});
```

**If you are just trying to store some arbitrary data, just use the first part of the above and call it like this:**

**Store the value:**

```
if (storage) {
   storage.setItem('key', 'value');
}
```

**Retrieve the value:**

```
if (storage) {
    storage.getItem('key');
}
```